# Pandas index error

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas

I am trying to use `train_test_split` to split my data. However, I am getting an index error. I pasted part of the error message below. I am using Python 3.5 version and `sklearn` 0.18.1. The code worked with my previous dataset that was different. Features here are in Pandas `DataFrame` and labels are in Pandas
`Series`.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.4, random_state=1)

KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last)
/apps/anaconda/anaconda-3.5/lib/python3.5/site-
    packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:<br><br>
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4443)()<br><br>
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4289)()<br><br>
pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13733)()<br><br>
pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13687)()<br><br>
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: You seem to suggest problem comes from that new dataset. But, you just don't describe/show it. Are there partial strings in there?  BTW your question might better fit with Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas indexes differently:

```
X[some_slice]   # in Numpy is NOT equal to
df[some_slice]  # in Pandas, but is instead equal to
df.iloc[some_slice]
```

You can cast your `features` dataframe into numpy array by calling `.values` on them right before splitting:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
    train_test_split(features.values, labels.values, test_size=0.4, random_state=1)
```